# В owl.carousel класс применяется только к первым 3 изначально выведенным на экран обьектам

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

```
var close='<button title=\"Close (Esc)\" type=\"button\" class=\"mfp-close\">&times;</button>';
$('.sect1 .owl-stage .active').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    var thiss=$(".clicked").clone().removeAttr("class").removeAttr("style").addClass("custom");
    $("#test-popup").html(thiss).append(close);
    $("#test-popup .read_more").parent().html( $("#test-popup .read_more").parent().find(".full_text").html() );
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");

});
```

Через этот скрипт я пытаюсь скопировать слайд овл карусели и вставить его в магнифик-попап окно но это на данный момент работает только с первыми тремя изначально отображаемыми слайдами

Comment: Используйте делегирование: `$('body').on('click', '.sect1 .owl-stage .active', function () {});`

Comment: Спасибо, все работает